# OCCI C++ app undefined reference

Tags: c++, oracle, cmake, clion, occi

I started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36292869/1593961) but so much has changed I thought it best to start a new question, especially since I *think* the CMake issue in the that question is solved.

**Background**
I'm trying setup a basic shell of a project that involves connecting a C++ midtier to an Oracle 12c database.

**Environment**
 1. MinGW-64 (x86_64-4.9.1-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v3-rev2)
 2. Windows 7 64-bit
 3. CLion 2016.1.1 (so I'm using CMake 3.5.1)
 4. All of the OCCI DLLs are in system32.
 5. Both the libs and the dlls are in `C:/Users/hurst/libs`

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(Oracle)
#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH C:/Users/hurst/libs)

find_library(OCCI1 oraociei12)
find_library(OCCI2 oci)
find_library(OCCI3 orannzsbb12)
find_library(OCCI4 oraocci12)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        src/main.cpp
        include/occi.h)

add_executable(Oracle ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Oracle ${OCCI1} ${OCCI2} ${OCCI3} ${OCCI4})
```

**Code**

```
#include <occi.h>

using namespace oracle::occi;

int main()
{
    Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();
    Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
}
```

**Error**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\hurst\.CLion2016.1\system\cmake\generated\Oracle-6ad0652d\6ad0652d\Debug --target Oracle -- -j 8
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable C:\Users\hurst\ClionProjects\Oracle\output\Debug\Oracle.exe
CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/hurst/ClionProjects/Oracle/src/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::Mode, void*, void* (*)(void*, unsigned long long), void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned long long), void (*)(void*, void*))'
C:/Users/hurst/ClionProjects/Oracle/src/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `oracle::occi::Environment::terminateEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir\build.make:100: recipe for target 'C:/Users/hurst/ClionProjects/Oracle/output/Debug/Oracle.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [C:/Users/hurst/ClionProjects/Oracle/output/Debug/Oracle.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Oracle.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Oracle.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Oracle.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Oracle] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Oracle.dir/rule' failed
makefile:117: recipe for target 'Oracle' failed
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

**Edit**
As suggested here is the verbose error output:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\hurst\.CLion2016.1\system\cmake\generated\Oracle-6ad0652d\6ad0652d\Debug --target Oracle -- -j 8
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:\Users\hurst\ClionProjects\Oracle -BC:\Users\hurst\.CLion2016.1\system\cmake\generated\Oracle-6ad0652d\6ad0652d\Debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
C:/Users/hurst/Downloads/x86_64-4.9.1-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v3-rev2/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 Oracle
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/hurst/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Oracle-6ad0652d/6ad0652d/Debug'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:\Users\hurst\ClionProjects\Oracle -BC:\Users\hurst\.CLion2016.1\system\cmake\generated\Oracle-6ad0652d\6ad0652d\Debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\hurst\.CLion2016.1\system\cmake\generated\Oracle-6ad0652d\6ad0652d\Debug\CMakeFiles 2
C:/Users/hurst/Downloads/x86_64-4.9.1-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v3-rev2/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 CMakeFiles/Oracle.dir/all
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/hurst/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Oracle-6ad0652d/6ad0652d/Debug'
C:/Users/hurst/Downloads/x86_64-4.9.1-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v3-rev2/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/Oracle.dir/depend
mingw32-make.exe[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/hurst/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Oracle-6ad0652d/6ad0652d/Debug'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\hurst\ClionProjects\Oracle C:\Users\hurst\ClionProjects\Oracle C:\Users\hurst\.CLion2016.1\system\cmake\generated\Oracle-6ad0652d\6ad0652d\Debug C:\Users\hurst\.CLion2016.1\system\cmake\generated\Oracle-6ad0652d\6ad0652d\Debug C:\Users\hurst\.CLion2016.1\system\cmake\generated\Oracle-6ad0652d\6ad0652d\Debug\CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
mingw32-make.exe[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/hurst/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Oracle-6ad0652d/6ad0652d/Debug'
C:/Users/hurst/Downloads/x86_64-4.9.1-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v3-rev2/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/Oracle.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/hurst/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Oracle-6ad0652d/6ad0652d/Debug'
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable C:\Users\hurst\ClionProjects\Oracle\output\Debug\Oracle.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir/objects.a
C:\Users\hurst\Downloads\x86_64-4.9.1-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v3-rev2\mingw64\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\Users\hurst\Downloads\x86_64-4.9.1-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v3-rev2\mingw64\bin\g++.exe   -std=c++11 -g   -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o C:\Users\hurst\ClionProjects\Oracle\output\Debug\Oracle.exe -Wl,--out-implib,C:\Users\hurst\ClionProjects\Oracle\output\Debug\libOracle.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir\linklibs.rsp
CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/hurst/ClionProjects/Oracle/src/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::Mode, void*, void* (*)(void*, unsigned long long), void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned long long), void (*)(void*, void*))'
C:/Users/hurst/ClionProjects/Oracle/src/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `oracle::occi::Environment::terminateEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [C:/Users/hurst/ClionProjects/Oracle/output/Debug/Oracle.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Oracle.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Oracle.dir\build.make:103: recipe for target 'C:/Users/hurst/ClionProjects/Oracle/output/Debug/Oracle.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/hurst/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Oracle-6ad0652d/6ad0652d/Debug'
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:69: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Oracle.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/hurst/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Oracle-6ad0652d/6ad0652d/Debug'
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Oracle.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/hurst/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Oracle-6ad0652d/6ad0652d/Debug'
makefile:120: recipe for target 'Oracle' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Oracle.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Oracle] Error 2
```

**Edit**
Based on some reading I've been doing on [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/1593961) I broke up the target_link_libraries() call so that it's one library per call:
target_link_libraries(Oracle ${OCCI1})
target_link_libraries(Oracle ${OCCI2})
target_link_libraries(Oracle ${OCCI3})
target_link_libraries(Oracle ${OCCI4})

I then tried to run it by moving ${OCCI2} up/down one and see if it succeeds (i.e. 1234, 2134, 1324, 1342) since ${OCCI2} is the OCI lib which represents the base C API of the Oracle interface.  It didn't work, same error.

Comment: Well, are you sure that find_library find something? `If nothing is found, the result will be <VAR>-NOTFOUND` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html AFAIR, for any .dll used by MinGW, you also should have corresponding .a file with exports.

Comment: Could you add `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` to your `CMakeLists.txt` (just after `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")`) and paste the detailed error report

Comment: @SergeiNikulov: CMake complains if `-NOTFOUND` variables are used with commands like `target_link_library`, so it looks like all `find_library` commands are succeed. But output of `make V=1` would be helpfull.

Comment: When you fill fix this problem, you will probably face another one MSVC and gcc use different ABI for C++. Probably it will be easier for you to use pure OCI with some open-source C++ wrapper.

Comment: PS: you can use this mackro: https://gist.github.com/ibre5041/fb9ce9b71afa50f8fde2#file-findoracle-cmake to detect Oracle installation. Do not copy anything into system32